# On iOS, what is the overall mechanism that anything gets drawn on the screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I wondered at first why if we subclass `UIView`, and we implement a `drawRect` method to be called, but at the same time, if we add buttons or labels to this view, and adjust their position coordinates, those will be re-drawn as well... so there seems to be a two-mechanism of drawing for this view, one for itself, and one for objects in this view.

But it turns out that, it seems every 1/60 of a second, the whole tree is just traversed. Starting from the top view object, iOS will visit all the children, and then call `drawRect` for `self`, and the children are also visited the same way, that the grandchildren are visited, and `drawRect` is called for each those first level children, as in:

```
-(void) processViewObject:(UIView *) obj {
    // pseudo code:
    foreach children "c" already sorted by zOrder from most negative to -1
        processViewObject(c)    // recursion

    if ([self needsUpdateOrNot] == YES)
        [self drawRect]

    foreach children "c" already sorted by zOrder from 1 to the greatest number
        processViewObject(c)   // recursion
}
```

and a call is made every 1/60 second, for

```
processViewObject(topViewObject);    //  start from the topmost view object
```

So that any view can draw itself in `drawRect`, and the view's children, if any of their position coordinates is modified, or if their content is changed, then the dirty bit `needsUpdateOrNot` has been set earlier, so their `drawRect` will be called to re-draw itself.

Or actually, if a view's dirty bit is set, then probably this bit will be passed to the children in the recursion, as in:

```
    foreach children "c" already sorted by zOrder from 1 to the greatest number
        processViewObject(c, [self needsUpdateOrNot])
```

so that if the parent's dirty bit is set, then the children will also need to be redrawn, for the whole picture inside this view to be drawn correctly.

Also, each of the nice looking button or labels are just a `UIView` object, with a `drawRect` that was already implemented that can draw a good looking image of what it is -- a button, a checkbox, a label, or any other widget.

Is this how the overall mechanism of how everything is drawn on the screen?  I hear of "never call `drawRect` ourselves, but let it be called", but never fully understand why, but if the above is the overall mechanism, then it looks like that's the reason why.

I wonder if this is the same mechanism that actually is almost the same as on Microsoft Windows or any GUI operating system, and on some game frameworks, I think no matter whether the dirty bit is set or not, everything is drawn because supposedly, things in a game move all the time, and the framework just draw all of them regardless every 1/60 of a second anyway.

The `zOrder` processing order above was in some framework's code, so that all the negative zOrder children are drawn first, and then `self` is drawn, and then all positive zOrder children are drawn.  (This is how the zOrder is achieved in a Painter Model way of painting things on the screen -- the latter drawn will cover up the earlier drawn.)  So `self` is a zOrder of `0` if relative to the children -- the zOrder number of `self` matters if it is relative to its own siblings, not relative to its children.

Is the above accurate?  If giving an answer, if possible, can part of the source code or reference be quoted, so that we know that is the standard or official way of how it works?

Comment: I still don't understand about the 1/60th concept.. I don't think iOS is no redrawing anything on a periodic (60 times in a second) basis. It will only redraw when redrawing is needed, like when a user interacts, or when application itself called setNeedsDisplay to invoke redrawing..Atleast that is way I understood the whole concept..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra if it is not called every 1/60 of a second, how can it check if some view's dirty bit is set and redraw it?  I suppose iOS can maintain a linked list of "dirty" views that need to be re-draw, so that if that list is empty, then no tree traverse need to be done... or else if there are dirty views, in this case iOS can find the top most common ancestor of these dirty views, and start the redraw at that top ancestor.

Comment: main run loop runs with a periodic frequency (say 1/60, I am not sure about that). But View updating only happens when needed. I don't know how run loop manages to identify which and which UIView's needed to be updated. May be it happens like how you said, by keeping a linked list.. May it traverse entire view hierarchy to poll and see whether it needs to be updated..May be some other way..I couldn't find any documents regarding that.. It seems like apple considering it as an implementation secret, which in no way needed by the developer..

Answer (score 6):

I think you're confusing compositing with drawing. The two are separate concepts, and they come into play at different points.

On iOS, each UIView is backed by a CALayer, which is effectively a lightweight wrapper around a rectangular OpenGL ES texture. When a UIView needs to be completely redrawn (the first time it appears, or when a redraw is forced through different circumstances), `-drawRect:` is triggered and Core Graphics is used to render vector graphics into a bitmap. That bitmap is then uploaded to the GPU via the CALayer and stored there.

When a view needs to be moved or have a simple transform applied to it (rotation, scaling, etc.), it isn't redrawn, the backing layer is simply moved and the layers in the visible scene are composited. Again, each view and subview has its own backing layer, so these are composited in their Z order in the view (layer) hierarchy. Compositing on the GPU is an incredibly fast operation, far faster than the initial drawing of the views. This is what enables smooth scrolling or animation in iOS, because these underlying rectangular images are just being moved around on the GPU and composited. It's also why having transparency in your views and layers slows down operations like scrolling, because compositing a non-opaque layer is significantly slower than opaque ones.

The overlapped portions of views are not redrawn when you move subviews or other views positioned above them, because compositing takes care of what is and is not visible. The only times that actual `-drawRect:` redrawing occurs is when you use `-setNeedsDisplay` to force a re-render or if you set `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` for a CALayer so that it redraws itself in response to a change in size or shape.

I believe that portion of the documentation that jturton links to is incorrect when it comes to iOS or to layer-backed views on the Mac. It appears to have been written when the Mac lacked Core Animation, and is the way that non-layer-backed NSViews are rendered, so it was probably copied and pasted from an older reference. This is not the case for layer-backed views, which do not redraw themselves when partially obscured. You can test this yourself by logging when `-drawRect:` is called within a layer-backed UIView, and you'll see that it's not triggered when views are simply moved around on top of one another.

Comment: Out of curiosity and wanting to learn myself, how did you learn so much about iOS and OpenGL in it? Ive seen your videos on iTunes and you've helped me a couple of times in some questions I have posted, but I think I'm on the wrong track because all these OpenGL ES 2.0 and CoreAnimation stuff still seems pretty complicated.

Comment: I completely missed your answer.. Better late than never.. Too bad question is closed..

Answer (score 2):

Views are drawn from the bottom (z-wise) up. There are various optimisations for opaque views etc. All views marked as dirty are redrawn at the end of the run loop - there isn't an every 1/60 second mechanism as you suspect.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/DrawingModel.html

Comment: if this model is strictly by the zOrder... then say if a view that has zOrder 10 and has an subview Foo with zOrder 10000, and another view with a zOrder of 100, and has a subview Bar with zOrder 1.  If Foo and Bar overlap, should Foo be on top or Bar be on top?  I think some framework let Bar be on top, because that will be how the "layer" is implemented in games.  But iOS might (or might not) be different (and what about HTML/CSS?)... which I will dig into later on...

Comment: Z order applies between peers (i.e subviews of the same view). it's not an integer which is compared between every view in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/DrawingModel.html) referenced by jrturton

> Drawing in iOS and Mac OS X follows one of two technology paths and is
>   based on a model in which views update their appearance on demand

I think that will settle about periodic update of views. Views only get updated on demand, which is understandable since for all its processing power iphone is still an embedded device. The less processor/memory work the better.. It has to think about battery life too..

> Some of the cases when the views are updated (from documentation
>   again)
>
> - The user moves or removes a view that was partially obscuring another    view.
> - The user scrolls a view off the containing scroll view and then    scrolls it back on.
> - Code makes a previously hidden view visible again by setting its    hidden property to NO.
> - Code explicitly invalidates a view To invalidate a view, and thus    mark it for redrawing, you call methods such as setNeedsDisplay or
>     setNeedsDisplayInRect: on the view.
>
> At the end of a cycle of the main event loop, a window proceeds down
>   its view hierarchy and requests **these** views to draw themselves by
>   calling their drawRect: methods.

So on main event loop, window (which is parent btw) traverses the entire tree hierarchy, but updates only the childs which needs to be updated.. Other views are kept as it is..

Comment: does the main event loop have a frequency... or is it ever running, so it can be greater than or smaller than 60 times per second?

Comment: That think I don't think is documented(Happy if someone correct me that I am wrong). I searched for it a bit too but not getting any info on it.. For opengl drawing 1/60 is desired normally. I don't have any info on main run loop frequency..

Comment: As I state in my answer, I believe that the first (and possibly second) item on that list of view update conditions is wrong for iOS. I've filed a documentation bug on this, but it looks to me like they copied this documentation from older Mac documentation involving NSView (where this is the case). UIViews are not redrawn when partially obscured or when UIViews move above them, and you can verify this by logging or placing a breakpoint around `-drawRect:` in a custom UIView to see when it is redrawn. They are merely composited in that case.